# Best way to display progress of wave file playback on waveform

Tags: wpf, clock, progress, naudio, waveform

I have a program that plays an mp4 video and uses the video's audio track to plot its waveform. How do I best denote the progress of the waveform plot( there are two samples per second) as it remains in sync with the video?

I would like the waveform and whatever I use to denote current time on the waveform plot to remain in sync with the video playing using the Timeline and Media Clock that I have implemented.

Other programs denote it by shading the area that has been played, or by keeping a bar that the waveform moves across where the bar denotes current time. I need some help in deciding which to implement and where to begin in the implementation.

If I was not clear, I would be happy to clarify the question, just let me know.

I am coding in C#, on a WPF program, using Naudio as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's up to you which you think looks best. The easier one to implement is a cursor on top of the waveform, since you can just move it as you are playing.

If you want to shade in the early part of the waveform, it very much depends on how you implemented the waveform drawing. If it is based on a series of vertical lines, then you can just change the colour of the lines before the now playing time.  But if you'd constructed the waveform as a polygon then it will be harder. There are some clever tricks you could use such as drawing a rectangle and telling WPF to clip it according to the waveform, but generally you'll find it easier to use the vertical line drawing approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "implement a cursor on top of the waveform"? I want the waveform moving in sync with the video being played. And need to denote somehow that the video is in sync with a point on the waveform. I understand the idea of changing the color of lines as they are being played. Right now I am using a list of points that are in a point collection and are assigned to a polyline.  My thought is to check the time on the "clock time invalidated" method and shade a portion up to the given point in the waveform based on current time. Thank you for your help @MarkHeath

Comment: OK I meant a static waveform with a moving cursor on top. It's usually the easiest one to implement.